# String splitting until sign foud

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have these items in the list:

```
App,Category,Rating,Reviews,Size,Installs,Type,Price,Content Rating,Genres,Last Updated,Current Ver,Android Ver

Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid & ScrapBook,ART_AND_DESIGN,4.1,159,19M,"10,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design,"January 7, 2018",1.0.0,4.0.3 and up

Coloring book moana,ART_AND_DESIGN,3.9,967,14M,"500,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design;Pretend Play,"January 15, 2018",2.0.0,4.0.3 and up

"U Launcher Lite – FREE Live Cool Themes, Hide Apps",ART_AND_DESIGN,4.7,87510,8.7M,"5,000,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design,"August 1, 2018",1.2.4,4.0.3 and up
```

You can see that data are splitted by comma (,) but for special items where comma does not work as a separator the item is placed into " ".

I want to create a splitted list, which would split all the items by comma except the ones which are put in "".

This the code I have so far to allocate the index of first " and the last ".

```
for each in range(len(google_data)):

    start_index = google_data[each].find('\"')
    endIndex = google_data[each].find('\"', start_index + 1)
    word_b_quotes = google_data[each][start_index:endIndex]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the csv module as below because the format it’s exactly the same:

```
from csv import reader

# test
input = ['A,B,C,"D12121",E,F,G,H,"I9,I8",J,K']

for item in reader(input):
    print item

# for the test input, prints
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D12121', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I9,I8', 'J', 'K']
```